# Uploading in HD

Tags: video

I am using WeVideo to create videos and want to link them onto a website.  I finished them in 4K and in 1080p, but when you pull up the link it goes to the next to lowest resolution.  I want it automatically to view in the resolution that I saved it in.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload your videos, do you edit them afterwards?  From looking at the documentation, Wevideo will support up to 4k (depending on your plan).  However, in the finishing your video section of their help, it mentions picking a picking a quality level when you upload or edit.  The available quality levels will depend on the plan you purchased.

I looked at the plans, the free plan will only allow up to 480k resolution.  To get higher resolution, you need to purchase a plan.

Try editing them right after upload and choosing the highest quality setting available to you.  That way it will not default to Wevideo's standard resolution.  It may be that if no quality is selected, the lowest one is the default, as that will play on the widest combination of bandwidth, device and video player.